# Communicating Between Docker Containers - Common Techniques

Tags: docker, docker-container

I'm getting started learning docker (And micro services in general) and I've got about as far as building a silly little "hello world" type app (1 as a .Net Core console app and another as an ASP.NET Core  web app) on windows.

My next milestone is to have 2 containers communicate with eachother, just sending some kind of simple message back and forth.

What techniques are commonly used to achieve communication between containers?

My initial thought was to set up a queue for outgoing and incoming messages for a container, so it doesn't need to concern itself with discovering and talking directly to another container.

Is that a common strategy or is there a better docker-y way of doing it?

If queues are a good choice, what are people generally using with docker (Keeping in mind that it needs to run in a windows container and work with a C# client ideally)?

I've seen an image for rabbitmq for window on docker hub, and I've heard good things - never used it before though (I could never get it installed on my windows machine directly, but with docker I managed to get a working version up in minutes - gotta say I'm really having fun with docker so far).  I'm open to suggestions.

I've seen some people suggest restful apis for their containers, but that seems far more complicated, as you'd need to know the specific container you want to communicate with, and the receiving container would need to somehow confirm that you're authorized to communicate with it (I guess you'd have a special authorization container that mints tokens perhaps).

Answer (score 3):

> What techniques are commonly used to achieve communication between
>   containers?

Docker has the ability to create virtual networks. You can add multiple containers to the same network, and each container can communicate directly with other containers using the other container's name. The container name will act as a DNS name, and will be automatically resolved for containers in the same network.

> Concerning queues:

Queues or more generally messaging techologies are a good fit for microservices. Messaging allows for asynchronous communication, which is very good for scalabilty. Messaging is not very appropriate for a request/response type of communication, where the sender expects a direct response from the receiver. As the name suggests, they are better used for sending messages.(Think of sending an email, you don't block waiting for a reply)

On the other hand, Rest APIs are in the category of sychronous communication. They are the most popular way to expose APIs for request/response communication.

In general, REST APIs are easier to implement than messaging techniques. Messaging communication requires a messaging broker(such as Rabbitmq) that sit between the communication endpoints.

In conclusion, use rabbitmq if your communication is asynchronus. Otherwise, expose rest apis in your apps if you have a request/response communication senarios.

Finally, regardless of what you chose, docker networks will allow you to glue everything together. If you use rabbitmq, you add it to the network, and send messages to the **rabbitmq** (container name) host.

Answer (score 2):

Containers are nothing else than standard daemons/services that are run in an isolated environment. There are no special rules about making containers communicate.

Normally, you just want to connect containers to the same `network` and they will act as virtual servers connected to the same LAN and see each other through a standard network connection.

The usage of queues to share data is not IMHO a "container" thing but a microservice good practice.

To summarize, you have to distinguish about low level network connection between containers and high level logical data exchange between services.